# LINQ Returning string array from DB.ExecuteQuery

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am simply trying to return a list of strings (just one field in a table) using the LINQ function Db.Executequery, but the following does not compile

```
Dim names = datacontext1.ExecuteQuery(of String()) _
      ("Select customerName from customers",nothing)
```

It looks like I cannot simply return a list of strings, it has to be a user defined class. (I tried just String, List(of String),etc but no luck.)   This is kind of cumbersome, because I cannot be declaring a class for each and every string field. (BTW, this will be a dynamic query, that is why I am not using the ORM mapping features)

The following does compile:

```
dim customerList = datacontext1.ExecuteQuery(of Customer) _ 
        ("Select * from customers",nothing)
```

Comment: I guess mixing and matching linq vs non linq

Comment: This is just an example. The column name IS customerName. Is it legal to use: db.ExecuteQuery(of String)(query, parameters) ? This is the actual error: 

Error 6 Type argument 'String' must have a public parameterless instance constructor to satisfy the 'New' constraint for type parameter 'TResult'.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. ExecuteQuery is perfectly legal in LINQ,

Comment: Sorry i mean if linq ain't flexible rifle off a non linq query

Comment: Can we tag this as vb.net or something too

Comment: Whatever your query is, you could probably do it just fine with EF/LINQ.  You just don't know how.  As for the string part, that should work.  Looks like you are trying to pass in a parameter, but the query you wrote does not require one (Remove the `nothing` parameter).

Answer (score 1):

The following should run just fine (assuming northwind database):

```
Dim names = datacontext1.ExecuteQuery(of String()) _
      ("SELECT contactname FROM customers")
```